# Calculate running total for a prior year

Tags: dax

The following code works properly, calculates the sum of CLIN Total for all of FY 2021.  I am trying to calculate the sum up to today's date, i.e., if today is July 01,2022, I want to calculate the sum  for FY 2021 through July 01, 2021.

```
Cum FY21 Invoice Total = 
     CALCULATE(
       SUM('Invoice Amounts'[CLIN Total]),
        FILTER(
            ALL('Calendar'),
            'Calendar'[Fiscal Year] = 2021
                && 'Calendar'[Date] < MAX('Calendar'[Date])
                && 'Calendar'[Date] < NOW())
                 )
```

I tried many variations of the following to replace the second filter, but can't find the right command. Dax doesn't seem to accept the now() in this context, but I'm not sure what the right one should be.

```
&&'Calendar'[Date]< DATEADD(now(),-1,YEAR)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach should help you to solve the issue.

```
VAR FirstDayThisYear = 
        SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(STARTOFYEAR(Calendar'[Date])
VAR LastDayThisYear = 
        SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(
                          LASTDATE(Calendar'[Date])
        )
VAR SetOfDates= 
        DATESBETWEEN(
                    Calendar'[Date]
                    ,FirstDayThisYear 
                    ,LastDayThisYear 
        )
RETURN 
        CALCULATE(
            SUM('Invoice Amounts'[CLIN Total]),
        ,SetOfDates= 
        )
```